# Scaling and positioning with svg and html

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an html file which contains an SVG image in it. I have an eye animation that follows the cursor that i want to put in the lens. The problem is I dont really know how to do it.

I tried using parent container but that did not work with SVG + HTML.
I also tried using media queries, but that only limits my sizes which is what Im not trying to do.

EDIT: Im running everything in angular if it helps.

HTML ( the svg): https://jsfiddle.net/nitko_i_nista/kjhx4mer/

CSS:

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:#333;
}
.eye {
    width: 115px;
    height: 105px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    top: 15.5%;
    left: 28.2%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: 60% 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fakeeye {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: auto;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
    border-radius: 60% 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ball{
    width:13px;
    height:13px;
    background:#222f3e;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:18px solid #576574;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);          
}
.shut{
    width:125px;
    height:118px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    z-index:999;
}
.shut span{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:0%;
    background:#0072e2;
    border-radius: 0 0 60% 60%;
    transition:0.4s all;
}
.eye:hover > .shut span{
    height:100%;
}
```

Do I have to use some editing tool to cut the eye in and make the project again? I really dont want that since im VERY inexperienced with those.

What I want to do (as pointed by a nice lad) is that the eye always stays in the lens (regardless of size). When I zoom in or out, the positions are the same (using a centering css trick). The eye for the code is not mine (https://codepen.io/guldus/pen/xmpVRb?editors=1100). I just thought it would be cool to add it into the lens, but im inexperienced in manipulating SVG.

Comment: Could you explain your problem some more? What's not working as it should, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to make it responsive. When I zoom in and out, the eye stays in the lens. Thats about it.
Edit: A friend of mine recommended using editing software (photoshop), but im pretty bad at those and I think it wont format it correctly, prompting me to redo the entire thing.

Comment: Perhaps try using percentage values instead of pixel values for width and height of the eye?

Comment: @04FS you sure we looking at the same fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would want to apply a 100% to width and height. This would allow your element to scale 100% of it's parent's height and width. Because you are talking about responsive work, have you consider looking into bootstrap?

Also I could not  zoom in or out in your fiddle.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that aswell. Defining an id and/or class to the SVG and html divs. But it doesnt seem to be working. I removed the `max-width` and `max-height` out of the css classes and toyed around with them, but none of them actually change the size. I feel really stupid here. Am I missing some basic css rule ???

Comment: absolutely NO reason why you should say that. nothing wrong in asking questions. that's why stack overflow was made.

IF you get ride of the " viewBox="0 0 854.56 300" you might find it following to the container, however the visual break. Sorry if I was of not much help.